# Gmail API access token with PHP curl

Tags: php, curl, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

Facing issue while retrieving token for API call. Here is my code

```
$authUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $authUrl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'code' => $code,
    'client_id' => CLIENT_ID,
    'client_secret' => CLIENT_SECRET,
    'redirect_uri' => $redirectURL,
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
));

$http_data = curl_exec($curl);  
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($http_data);
```

$http_data is saying invalid request.

My task is to get all emails in my gmail account and I think for that I need access token. Please advise.

Thanx in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OAuth 2.0 in php using curl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423924/oauth-2-0-in-php-using-curl)

Comment: still getting invalid_request error. Something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0):

First you appear to be adding all of the parameters as part of the HTTP GET string this is a **HTTP POST** call.  Also you appear to have forgotten to include the **code** you got from the first part of the auth flow.

> That is the Authentication Code, it is used to request a refresh
>   token.   It is displayed to the user in the body of the html as well
>   as in the title of the page. To get a Refresh Token you POST the
>   Authentication code back to Google. Note: This is a HTTP Post you cant
>   just place it in a browser that would be a HTTP Get. Note:
>   grant_type=authorization_code

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
code={Your code from the first part of flow}&client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&grant_type=authorization_code
```

Note have you considered using the [Google APIs PHP Client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) which will handle all of this for you?

Code ripped from my [Google 3 legged Oauth2 flow](http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/) article.

Comment: $authUrl = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
$curl = curl_init();
   curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
            'code' => $code,
            'client_id' => CLIENT_ID,
            'client_secret' => CLIENT_SECRET,
            'redirect_uri' => getRedirectUri(),
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
        ),
        CURLOPT_URL => $authUrl,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true
    )); 
    $http_data = curl_exec($curl);  
    curl_close($curl);

Comment: Using above code to get token. But getting blank response. Here $code is 4/EfvRZ7kEGBOK7TXfuYba4mDAdRUakUbd5is4IdEYJ8Q# Please advice what is wrong with the code. Sorry unable to format code.