# use javascript and php with google to authenticate a user

Tags: javascript, php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'd like to use Google sign-in to authenticate posts to my PHP. On the webpage there is a Google sign-in button (which works) and then various functions post the `id_token` obtained from Google to my PHP:

```
function getAuth() {
            var id_token = theUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
            var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
            oReq.onload = function() {
                console.log(this.responseText);
            }
            oReq.open("POST", "databaseAccess.php", true);
            oReq.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            oReq.send("oc="+id_token);
        }
```

on the server-side:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["oc"])) {
    $code = $_POST["oc"];
    $client_id = "xxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    $redirect_uri = "http://myDomain/responder.html";
    $client_secret = "xxxxxxxx";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'scope' => 'profile',
        'client_id' => $client_id,
        'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri
    ));

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
}

echo($data);

?>
```

But the result is "1", which I don't think I should be expecting.

From a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423924/oauth-2-0-in-php-using-curl#25425751) I also tried:

```
    $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
            'code' => $code,
            'client_id' => $client_id,
            'client_secret' => $client_secret,
            'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code'
        ));

        $data = curl_exec($ch);
echo($data)
```

But this returns nothing: a stoney silence from Google. According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) I can also just do a more simple

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token=XYZ123
```

so in the PHP file, I tried:

```
$data = http_build_query(array(
        'id_token' => $code
    ));
    echo("DATA: ".$data);

    $context = stream_context_create(array(
    'https' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $data
    )
));

// Make POST request
    $response = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo', false, $context);
    echo("PHP OUT: ".$response);
```

With this I get the error:

```
either access_token, id_token, or token_handle required
```

Typing into a web browser:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/tokeninfo?id_token=xxx0Cc6
```

with a valid token I receive from the web page's javascript gives me an appropriate result:

```
{
 "issued_to": "8jijijijijijihb.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "audience": "8jijijijijijij20hb.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "user_id": "1128jijijijijij38756",
 "expires_in": 2412,
 "email": "me@googlemail.com",
 "verified_email": true
}
```

Hopefully someone can tell me how, in my PHP I can receive a result just like this. Using the PHP beta api has also proved fruitless on my lowly server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token={$oc}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


$data = curl_exec($ch);
echo($data)
```

Comment: Thanks, but Im not sure what you're referring to with `$oc`.

Comment: Create a variable called: $oc = $_POST['oc'];